# How can I redirect with iframe from http://sitename.com to https://sitename.net

Tags: html, http, redirect, https, dns

I have 2 domains on Aruba (without hosting plan, just domain) which are sitename.com and sitename.it. Then I have another domain in serverplan with the hosting and WordPress installed on, which is sitename.net

I have activated the SSL to have secure connection with https//
then I redirect with the iframe the 2 aruba domains, by selecting https:// from the menu in aruba redirect section, but something doesn't work.

(iframe because I want to show and index the sitename.com one, as principal link)

I tried to install and manage with "Redirections", the WordPress plugin but resetting redirects from here, nothing changed.

If I go to sitename.com and sitename.it, the connection is still not secure.
Where can I start?

Comment: Thank you so much Jason, and sorry for my bad english! Still learning :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.